# Symfony2 validation - How to use a value from the form?

Tags: php, validation, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a form where I have to fill in some information.
For one of the fields of the form, I need to create a custom validator.
In fact, I need to valdiate that the entered string is in a specific format like ab.123.cd

I am able to validate this by using regexp, but the "ab" should be eqal to another field of my form, so I need to access this other field in my validator class.

Here is my validator:

```
public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
{       
    preg_match('/[^\/]+/i', $value, $publisherDoiAbbr);
    if($publisherDoiAbbr[0] !== $enquiry->getPublisher()->getDoiAbbreviation()) {
        $this->context->addViolation($constraint->message_publisher_DOI);
    }
    $this->context->addViolation($constraint->message_journal_DOI);
}
```

I need here the **$enquiry->getPublisher()->getDoiAbbreviation()**

Do you know how can I access the values of my form in the validator class?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is make a "CLASS CONSTRAINT" validator.

Scroll down here:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html

until you get to the class constraint section for an example.

================================================================

**I don't understand what is te "getTargets()"**

Add this method to your Constraint class (not the validator class)

```
class MyConstraint extends Constraint
{
    public function getTargets()
    {
        return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
    }
```

Once that has been added then your validator method will receive an object instead of a single value.

```
class MyValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        // $value will be an object, adjust your code accordingly
```

Comment: Thank you @Cerad. I'm afraid I don't understand the example from Symfony. Do you have a real example. At the moment, I don't understand what is te "getTargets()" function, where to implement it and what should this function return. How can I with that access the values from my form.